# How can I use strings inside ddply functions?

Tags: r, dplyr

Just as an illustrative example, to create a function similar to `countif` in excel, here is what I have tried to somehow use the string "mycolumn" inside the ddply "countif" variable definition below:

```
df <- c("a","a","b","c","c") %>% data.frame(stringsAsFactors = F)
colnames(df) <- "mycolumn"
x <- "mycolumn"
countif <- function(df,x ) {
y <- which(colnames(df)==x)
result1 <- ddply(df,x,nrow) #this works, but I can't use the x argument
result2 <- ddply(df,x,summarise, countif=length(df[,y])) #not working
result3 <- ddply(df,x,summarise, countif=length(parse(text=x))) #not working
    }
```

As you can see below, only `result1` works, but I need a way to be able to use my `mycolumn` string in the ddply function instead of solely relying on `nrow`. Many thanks.

```
> result1
  mycolumn V1
1        a  2
2        b  1
3        c  2
> result2
  mycolumn countif
1        a       5
2        b       5
3        c       5
> result3
  mycolumn countif
1        a       1
2        b       1
3        c       1
```

Comment: Have you looked into do()?

Comment: Can you please elaborate? how would I use it in this case?

Comment: What is the 'if' in the that you're looking for? it seems that you just count them by groups (my column). You can get the same results with group_by() and summarize().

Comment: Yes, I imagine there are other ways, but for other functions I need to understand how to convert "mycolumn" into mycolumn that ddply can understand.

Comment: @gpier `ddply` is kind of deprecated, you will find much easier to use its successors: `dplyr`, `tidyr` (generally called `tidyverse`, [have alook here](https://www.tidyverse.org/)

Comment: @GGamba, thank you for the tip, what function in tidyverse would be similar to ddply?

Comment: see @Shinobi_atobe answer

Answer (score 1):

not entirely sure if I get what you're after, but my best guess would be something like the below

```
library(dplyr)

df <-  data.frame(mycolumn = c("a","a","b","c","c"))

result1 <- df %>% group_by(mycolumn) %>% tally()

result3 <- df %>% filter(mycolumn %in% c("a", "b")) %>% group_by(mycolumn) %>% tally()
```

You can play around with the conditional inside the filter function

Comment: Yes, I imagine there are other ways, but for other functions I need to understand how to convert "mycolumn" into mycolumn that ddply can understand. Hoy can I use a string into ddply in general...

Comment: To have the same result as ddply, how would you then recombine result1 into df?